# Show react-bootstrap modal inside specific div

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

Is there a way to show the react-bootstrap modal inside a specific div and not the entire screen?
The code looks like this:

```
<div>
  <textarea />
  <Modal>....</Modal>
</div>
```

I want to show the modal on top of textarea. Any help?

**PS** Got the solution. Had to create a wrapper for modal and adjust styling.

Comment: Modal always fills the entire screen. Try popover instead : https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/overlays/#popovers

Comment: Found the solution.